# Performance of recursively searching for indices in large sets of data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I came across a question today of search efficiency for large sets today and I've done by best to boil it down to the most basic case. I feel like this sort of thing probably relates to some classic problem or basic concept I'm missing, so a pointer to that would be great.

Suppose I have a table definition like

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    id int,
    type bool,
    reference int,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(reference) REFERENCES foo(id),
    UNIQUE KEY(reference)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

Populated with n rows where n/2 are randomly assigned type=1. Each row references another **with its same type** except for the first, which has reference=null.

Now we want to print all items with type 1. I assume that at some point, it will be faster to recursively call something like

```
function printFoo1($ref){
    if($ref==null)
        return;
    $q = 'SELECT id, reference FROM foo WHERE id='.$ref;
    $arr = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query($q) );
    echo $arr[0];
    printFoo1($arr[1]);
}
```

As opposed to

```
function printFoo2($ref){
    $q = 'SELECT id FROM foo WHERE type=1';
    $res = mysql_query($q);
    while( $id = mysql_fetch_array($res) ){
        echo $id[0];
    }
}
```

The main point here being that function 1 searches for "id", which is indexed, whereas function 2 has to make n/2 comparisons that don't result in a hit, but that the overhead of multiple queries is going to be significantly greater than the single SELECT.

Is my assumption correct? If so, how large of a data set would we need before function 1 outperforms function 2?

Comment: i think the cost based optimizer in Oracle at least would account for which is better based on current table statistics...

Comment: @Randy Thanks, I wasn't familiar with that. I'll give it a look.

Comment: This code is an SQL-injection leak: `'SELECT id, reference FROM foo WHERE id='.$ref;`, change it into `"SELECT id, reference FROM foo WHERE id='$ref';"` Note the use of single quotes. Without those your `mysql_real_escape_string()` will not work.

Comment: that is not entirely true. There are some concerns with it, but this is an academic exercise, not an injection issue. With SQL you dont need to quote integers, and that does not actually address the injection, without the escaping. Even with escaping, an integer should not need to be quoted. Quoting strings opens doors to type mismatch errors as well since they are used to signify strings and trigger type casts in route to the database.  

A less interesting example of problems you can run into using quoted numbers: 
http://pento.net/2009/03/03/dont-quote-your-numbers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is a bit difficult to parse, but ill start at the top:

Your first function does not return all of the elements with type = 1. It returns all of the elements that are dependent (based on references) to the element you pass in. From the PHP standpoint, since the link/handle is already open there is a non-trivial overhead from your function call with each successive request, not to mention the string concatenation incurring a cost with each execution of that line.

Typically it is better to use the second function styling because it only queries the database one time and will return the elements you are requesting without further work. It will come down to a profiler of course, to determine which is going to return faster, but from my tests the second is hands down the better choice:

This was executed with n = 5000 elements in the db (n/2 = 2500 type 1 and passing in reference = highest id with type = 1 from query of db).

```
printFoo1: 3.591840 seconds
printFoo2: 0.010340 seconds
```

It wouldn't really make sense for it to work any other way. If you were able to do what you propose that would make `JOIN` calls have to perform less efficient as well.

**Code**

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT MAX( id ) as `MAX_ID` FROM `foo` WHERE `type` = 1', $link);
$res2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

$id = $res2['MAX_ID'];

// cleanup result and free resources here

echo "printFoo1: ";
$start = microtime(true);
printFoo1($id);
echo microtime(true) - $start;

echo '<br />';

echo "printFoo2: ";
$start = microtime(true);
printFoo2();
echo microtime(true) - $start;

mysql_close($link);
```

All of this was tested on PHP 5.2.17 running on Linux

Comment: This is what I expected, but I didn't realize the disparity would be so large or that queries had quite so much overhead. I'm still curious to see if/when the times ever intersect; I'll test it out next time I've got access to my machine.Thank you for your very in-depth answer.